# Is there any open source library which does the job of a proxy server?

Tags: proxy

I am looking for a library which does the job of a http/https proxy server so that I can use it in my code. I do not want to write a complete proxy server on my own (that would be very difficult for me). So I am looking for such libraries.

I am writing the code in C language under Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many types of proxy servers: socks, ftp, http and so on.

Comment: oh! I am sorry I forgot to tell that I am looking for a http/https proxy server library

Answer (score 1):

Check out this.

http://www.vorburger.ch/projects/proxy/

And this.

[c http proxy library](http://www.google.ru/#sclient=psy&hl=ru&newwindow=1&q=c+http+proxy+library&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=3f840bab7e411dc5)

And this question.

[Open source HTTP or HTTPS proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994846/open-source-http-or-https-proxy)

Comment: thanks for the help and efforts.
but I need a library whose functions I can call from my C code. I don't want to install a proxy server or hack into its source code and make a change there to get my work done. I am still searching for it.

but anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at this question, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737309/how-to-write-a-http1-0-proxy-server-in-c-in-linux